# Ubuntu 18.10 - Issue with screen inactivity and lock screen

Tags: gnome-shell, lock-screen, idle

Clean installation of Ubuntu 18.10 beta

I want the screen to turn off after 1 minute of inactivity, but I do not want the system to be locked when it is activated again. So I do :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 60
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
```

The screen turns off after 1 minute of inactivity. The problem is that after that when I try to access the system it is stuck at a purple screen similar to the one of the lock screen but with no input form for password. The only way to access the system, is to suspend the system and then resume.

Do you have any view on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also experiencing this, and found that it was due to a Gnome Shell Extension.

My experience is that logging in initially was fine. Logging out and logging back in was fine, but resuming from a 'lock' status was causing the issue. I simply could not get the 'shade' to swipe up to reveal the password input. No swipes on the trackpad, mouse, or keyboard presses would reveal the input.

Try disabling all extensions and then logging out (not just locking) so that your session is restarted.

After that you can go in and start enabling extensions one at a time, log out, log back in, then lock (super + l). If you can't log in, the last extension you enabled is the culprit and you'll have to either way for an update to be compatible, and it'd be super awesome if you go let the extension developer know on the extensions.gnome.org page.

Comment: To recover from the "broken lock-screen", I can press super + L and then get to the proper lockscreen.

Answer (score 8):

Same here after upgrading from 18.04 to 18.10. First tried to disable my extensions. After about an hour working I tried to lock my machine and failed. So not a solution for me.

Googling some more, when I came across [Lock screen curtain in Ubuntu 18.10 won't open](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086042/lock-screen-curtain-in-ubuntu-18-10-wont-open) and a suggestion there was to remove and add gdm3 from terminal:

```
$ sudo apt remove gdm3
$ sudo apt install gdm3 
$ reboot
```

Now, half a day working later, 10+ locks, the issue has not returned.

#### Update 2018-11-16

Issues have returned unfortunately. After going through the [bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1769383) this suggestion came by:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock transparency-mode FIXED
```

For me this seems to work.

Comment: I've been fighting this one for a while, and the gsettings change worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, install dconf-editor:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

After, start dconf-editor and open path **/org/gnome/desktop/lockdown/**

Make sure, option [disable-lock-screen is disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYoIz.png).

The same with gsettings:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the isue is a bit different.
I have 4 extensions installed : Auto Move Windows, Gsconnect (from Github), KstatusnotifierItem and Openweather.

All is fine for several days, then suddenly I face the purple screen after black screen timeout.
I can then press "Super-l" then "Esc" keys to login again... But then ALL extensions are disabled. So I reboot, and all extensions are back again.

Looks like a bug in 18.10, got no such issue with 18.04.

Comment: Did you file or find a related bug?

Comment: No, found (and filled)  nothing... I will investigate a bit further, as this is really annoying. One more thing I noticed is that all icons in the top bar has disappeared when logging back. 
Will deactivate things one by one and see how it goes.  
Checking also logs with "sudo journalctl -f /usr/bin/gnome-shell".

Comment: Perhaps it is related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1769383

Comment: Yes, it looks like similar, at least related to that problem. Anyway, since I have disabled "KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support" extension, issue has disappeared...

Comment: Correction : KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support" extension disabled seems only to reduce occurence of the issue... :-(

Comment: When all Gnome extensions have been disabled after a lockscreen, you don't have to reboot. It is sufficient to restart the Gnome Shell:
Alt-F2 R