# Lock screen curtain in Ubuntu 18.10 won't open

Tags: lock-screen, 18.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.10, the lock screen curtain does not respond to any input. As I understand, it should be possible to swipe up with the mouse, press <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> or just start typing the password.

None of these works, and there is no option to exit the curtain other than killing the computer and then restart. It makes the computer almost useless.

If anyone have a solution for this, I would be extremely grateful!

Comment: You upgraded or fresh installed 18.10

Comment: I upgraded from 18.04 - where everything worked fine.

Comment: generally upgrading have issues like this.. i am using fresh install of 18.10 and there is no problem. I think re installation of gdm may help.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/829108/739431

Comment: use these 3 commands in terminal one after one. `sudo apt remove gdm3` `sudo apt install gdm3` `reboot` i hope issue will be solved.

Comment: Thanks alot!
The problem remained after the reinstallation and reboot.
I uninstalled gdm3 again and selected sddm as default instead. That seems to work better.
Thanks!

Comment: That's great you found alternative.. But as you are good with your display manager sddm.. after some time try to install gdm3 and reconfigure with commands in linked question and answer when you are free.. Thank You.

Comment: I think I have the same issue. For now I press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and after few seconds it opens Login screen.